# Convert array elements to single number

Tags: matlab

I have an array `A=[1,0,1,1,1,0]`. I want to convert it to a decimal number `B = 101110`. I have tried all the conversion functions, but couldn't find an appropriate solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done quite simply this way:

```
B = sum(A.*10.^(numel(A)-1:-1:0))
B =
      101110
```

What it does is take each number in `A` and multiply it with `10^n` where n corresponds to the value appropriated with that place in the vector. By taking the sum of this new vector you'll get your answer. 
It's the equivalent of:

```
1*10^5 + 0*10^4 + 1*10^3 + 1*10^2 + 1*10^1 + 0*10^0
```

As Luis commented, it can also be done as

```
B = 10.^(numel(A)-1:-1:0) * A(:);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can make a function

```
function decimal = array2dec(A)
nA = length(A);
decimal = 0;
for i = 1:nA
    decimal = decimal + A(i)*10^(nA-i);
end
```

save this.

```
>> A = [1,0,1,1,1,0];
>> dec = array2dec(A)
>> dec =
>>    101110
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another approach. Probably not very fast, though:

```
base2dec(A+'0',10)
```